# ROS2 and custom mutexes

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Can a node which waits on a generic mutex block ROS2? For example, is it that SingleThreadedExecutor may "get out of threads" in such a case? If yes, does ROS2 provide its own mutexes, which "yield" a waiting thread back to the executor?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/307821/ros2-and-custom-mutexes/) by [uthinu](https://answers.ros.org/users/37306/uthinu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 118 on 2018-11-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you block (for any reason, including acquiring a mutex) in a callback and are using a SingleThreadedExecutor, it will prevent other callbacks from being called.

You can either, avoid blocking and defer the work (asynchronous programming) or you can use a multi threaded executor, which can still get exhausted, but at least will allow other callbacks to be called at the same time so long as there are more thread available.

If you just need to ensure two callbacks do not get called at the same time (you would otherwise use a scoped lock with a shared mutex in the root of each callback) then you can instead put them in the same "MutuallyExclusiveCallbackGroup" (this is the default behavior if you just call `create_{timer, subscription, service, client}`) and the then the executor will ensure they are not called concurrently in a multi threaded executor. This prevents you from having N callbacks, all waiting on the same mutex, from consuming and blocking in all N threads of your multi threaded executor.

See:

- https://www.osrfoundation.org/wordpress2/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/ROSCON-2014-Why-you-want-to-use-ROS-2.pdf

  - slides 17-19
- https://vimeo.com/107531013

  - 13 min and on

We've got some documentation about executors and callback groups in the works but it's not public yet.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2018-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2